# Jade: Where is the documentation for template inheritance?

Tags: node.js, pug, template-engine

I don't see any documentation for the extends/block syntax at the Jade [language reference](http://jade-lang.com/reference/). Is that documentation just out of date? Is there any better documentation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think Jade documentation is rather up-to-date, however, it misses some parts, as you have pointed that out.

In order to extend your template by including other Jade files you can use [includes](http://jade-lang.com/reference/#includes). In order to create reusable blocks of Jade you can use [Mixins](http://jade-lang.com/reference/#mixins).

I would also recommend going through all the [examples](https://github.com/visionmedia/jade/tree/master/examples) supplied with Jade. For `extends` mechanism you can focus on [extend.jade](https://github.com/visionmedia/jade/blob/master/examples/extend.jade), [extend-layout.jade](https://github.com/visionmedia/jade/blob/master/examples/extend-layout.jade) and [extend.js](https://github.com/visionmedia/jade/blob/master/examples/extend.js).

It would be great to have decent documentation, but on the other hand, Jade template language seems to be simple enough to be mastered, experimenting for a few days with the supplied examples.

I hope that will help.